# repeated operation in pandas with Groupby and sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been trying to get my head around the following problem for some time now. Hope someone can help me out. I try to sum up numbercounts (e.g. births) for different areas. As shown in the table below, I have a dataset wherein, as an example, areas 1 and 2 come toghether in the fused area4. Area3 is unaffected.

```
import pandas as pd
data1  = { 
"OldArea" : ['area1','area2','area3'],
"numbercount" : [10,20,5],
"FusedIntoArea" : ['area4','area4','area3']
}
frame1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['OldArea', 'FusedIntoArea', 'numbercount'])
frame1
```

I want to add up the numercount for area1 and area2 (10 + 20) into the area 4 (30). The numbercount for area3 stays the same (5). This works by using groupby and sum to get a pd.series series1 as shown below.

```
series1 = frame1.groupby(['FusedIntoArea'])['numbercount'].sum()
series1
```

The problem is that I want to extend this groupby and sum operation for several fusions of areas through several years. The extended fusion data for the areas is shown in frame3. Area1 and area2 fuse to form area4 (just like before) but now there is more: in the year after that area4 and area3 fuse to form area5, whereas area6 stays the same through the years. The fusion data is in a format like the one in frame2 below:

```
data2 = {
'year0' : ['area1', 'area2', 'area3', 'area6'],
'year1' : ['area4', 'area4', 'area3', 'area6'],
'year2' : ['area5', 'area5', 'area5', 'area6']
}
frame2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['year0', 'year1', 'year2'])
frame2
```

The data for the numbercounts (e.g. births before a fusion or from the moment of a fusion onwards) is in a separate frame now, frame3.

```
data3  = { 
"area" : ['area1', 'area2','area3', 'area4', 'area5', 'area6'],
"numbercount" : [10,20,5,35, 15,25],
}
frame3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=['area', 'numbercount'])
frame3
```

The result that I am trying to get is the total numbercount (TotalNumber) for the newly formed areas5 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 after the fusion) and 6 (unchanged through the years) as shown in frame4. Any help is much appreciated. Should I maybe use a join or merge operation? Thanks in advance.

```
data4  = { 
    "OldAreas" :[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "NewArea" : ['area5','area5','area5','area5','area5','area6'],
    "TotalNumber" : [85,85,85,85,85, 25]
}
frame4 = pd.DataFrame(data4, columns=['NewArea', 'TotalNumber'])
frame4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionnaries to map your existing data.

First create a dictionnary which tells you for every area in which area it fusing:

```
areas_to_fuse = dict(zip(frame2.year0.values, frame2.year2.values))
areas_to_fuse = {**areas_to_fuse,**dict(zip(frame2.year1.values, frame2.year2.values))}


{'area1': 'area5',
 'area2': 'area5',
 'area3': 'area5',
 'area4': 'area5',
 'area6': 'area6'}
```

This being done, you can create the `NewArea` column by using `replace` on `frame3['area']` (note that `replace` permits to keep the values not present in the keys of the dictionnary, if you prefer missing values, use `map`)

```
frame3['NewArea'] = frame3.area.replace(areas_to_fuse)
```

Then you can create a second dictionnary coding for every area which value corresponds, and map it to your column `NewArea`:

```
newvalues = frame3.groupby('NewArea').numbercount.sum().to_dict()
frame3['TotalNumber'] = frame3.NewArea.map(newvalues)
frame3[['NewArea','TotalNumber']]

    NewArea     TotalNumber
0   area5       85
1   area5       85
2   area5       85
3   area5       85
4   area5       85
5   area6       25
```